# In R markdown file, why can't I knit the file while it can run correctly

Tags: r

[image]
I want to load the package names `hflights`. I think I have load it correctly. And the code at line 64 and 65 can be run, when I the hint the knit button it keeps reminding me the problem is at there. But it can run, the result is shown belown. I don't know why I can not knit my rmd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval= TRUE` to evaluate the chunk while knitting.  According to [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html)

> eval: Whether to evaluate a code chunk.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE}
library(hflights)   
data(hflights)

```

```{r getdata, cache = TRUE}
dim(hflights)
names(hflights)
```
````

---

-output

[image]